# Undefined reference to 'getpass' in c

Tags: c, codeblocks, getpass

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  char *itm;
  char *qnt;
  qnt,itm = getpass("");
  printf("%s %s ",qnt,itm);
    return 0;
}
```

So if i run this code in online compiler like replit , it runs without error . But when i run it in codeblock , it throws an error stating undefined reference to 'getpass' . how to fix this ?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: The manpage for `getpass` states you need to use `#include <pwd.h>`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Much of the documentation for `getpass` states clearly "this function is obsolete, do not use it".  Why are you using it?

Comment: The `getpass()` function is obsolete and has been withdrawn from POSIX.  It should not be used.  Among other issues, you may find -- as indeed you have done -- that some POSIX-compliant C implementations don't provide it at all.  And, of course, C implementations that are *not* POSIX compliant could never be assumed to provide it.

Comment: Also, I doubt qnt,itm = getpass("") does what you hope. A function can only return one thing. It's valid (but very, very odd) C, but qnt doesn't get assigned anything.